# OData IQueryable filter adding extra parentheses

Tags: c#, odata

I am querying an OData service list of products. The RequestUri for the entity is 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products'.
Products is an `IQueryable<Product>`.

In my code if am using Linq to get data from a certain date:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/");
// DHuSData class was auto generated from the OData $metadata
var odata = new DHuSData(uri); 
odata.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "MyPassword");
var query = odata.Products.Where(f => f.ContentDate.End > datetime).ToList();
```

However, the query does not work because the resulting Uri from the query has and extra set of parenthesis before the ?$filter:

```
https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products()?$filter=ContentDate/End gt datetime'2023-01-01T17%3A49%3A29.9719648-07%3A00'
```

Why is the Linq query adding these parenthesis and how can I remove them?

Edit*****

I was able to create a small reproduction of the code by implementing my own DataServiceContext

```
public Class TestOData
    {       
        private void CreateOdata()
        {
            var odata = new MyOdata(new Uri("https://myodata.com/dhus/odata/v1/"));
            var datetime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(15));
            IQueryable<MyProduct> query = odata.MyProducts.Where(f => f.ContentDate.End > datetime);
            DataServiceQuery serviceQuery = (DataServiceQuery)query;
            Console.WriteLine(serviceQuery.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }

    public class MyProduct
    {
        public TimeRange ContentDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyOdata : System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext
    {
        public MyOdata(System.Uri serviceRoot) :
                base(serviceRoot)
        {  }

        private System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<MyProduct> _MyProducts;
        public System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<MyProduct> MyProducts
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this._MyProducts == null))
                {
                    this._MyProducts = base.CreateQuery<MyProduct>("MyProducts");
                }
                return this._MyProducts;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried `AddQueryOption`, so it appears that it may not be Linq related

```
var formattedDate = datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            formattedDate = WebUtility.UrlEncode(formattedDate);
DataServiceQuery<MyProduct> selectedOrders = odata.MyProducts
    .AddQueryOption("$filter", string.Format("ContentDate/End gt '{0}'", formattedDate));
```

Comment: Could you share more code? How do you initialize _odata?

Comment: DHuSData class was auto generated from the OData $metadata. It is created using the OData generation extension in Visual Studio.
 ```   var _odata = new DHuSData(uri); ```

Comment: Here may be some usefull information for you - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4463e8f7-56c7-4d39-9d11-261f5d3c9ed5/dataservicecontext-createquery-method-issue-unwanted-parenthesis-in-operation-rest-url?forum=adodotnetdataservices

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution I found was to rewrite the Url when building the request:

```
//Add a handler in the initializer
_odata.BuildingRequest += OnBuildRequest;

//Then replace the '()' in the url
private static void OnBuildRequest(object sender, BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    string url = e.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
    url = url.Replace("()", "");
    e.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
}
```

Comment: Do you might know the answer to this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245865/copybatchrequestproperties-and-deleterequestcontainer-replacement-in-aspnetcore